# Load static images in HTML with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working with webpack 5.88.2. I can't figure out how to load images in HTML with Webpack. My index.html contains the following tag, but the image is not displayed:

```
<img src="/src/assets/images/pic.png">
```

Here is my Webpack configuration:

```
  module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.html$/i,
    loader: "html-loader",
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    //exclude: /\.lazy\.css$/i,
    //exclude: /theme-[A-Za-z]+\.css$/i,
    exclude: /themes(\/|\\)theme-[A-Za-z]+\.css$/i,
    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "url-loader",
        options: {
          limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
          name: 'images/[hash]-[name].[ext]'
        }
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.mp3$/,
    type: "asset/inline", //'url-loader'
  },
  {
    //test: /\.lazy\.css$/i,
    //test: /theme-[A-Za-z]+\.css$/i,
    test: /themes(\/|\\)theme-[A-Za-z]+\.css$/i,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "style-loader",
        options: { injectType: "lazySingletonStyleTag" },
      },
      "css-loader",
    ],
  }
],
```

},

plugins: [
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
title: 'title',
template: './src/index.html',
}),
new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
],

As you can see, I added an entry with `loader: "html-loader"`, but it does not work. I also read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46053801/loading-images-by-src-in-html-with-webpack) but I don't want to load images from JS (I already know how to do this).

Any help?

Comment: Why, though? Images, mp3, etc are just static assets. Put them in your asset dir, point at the right URL in your JSX, and done? There is no reason to make webpack do stuff with them?

Comment: The static images are not  in the dist folder when I run webpack, only if I write something like `import pic from "pic.png"` in my JS

Comment: @Fifi One possible solution could be to use the file-loader instead of the url-loader.

Comment: More of an opinion than an answer, but yeah: that's the problem with webpack. It has made people think that they need a build step for static assets, over-complicating something that's been the literal basis (and basics) of the web into a completely unnecessary build step: have your asset directory in a place where your server can serve them from, because your front-end code doesn't care where the images live in terms of the file system, it just needs to be able to load URLs to get images, mp3s, etc. This is not something webpack should ever have been used for =)

Comment: Yes I agree, but I'm convinced there is an option in `webpack.config.js` that will parse my HTML to copy the static assets in the dist folder.

Comment: Just upload images somewhere and point to them in your img src. Easiest way to habdle that

Comment: @AliBahrami with my Webpack configuration, the `dist` folder is erased every time rebuild the dist folder

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "html-bundler-webpack-plugin". The plugin resolves all source files of images, fonts, styles, scripts, etc., in the HTML and replaces the references with their output filenames in the generated HTML.

For example, there is an HTML with references to images:

simple *src/index.html*:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- you can specify any source files directly in HTML -->
  <link href="./images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
  <link href="./scss/styles.scss" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="./js/main.js" defer="defer"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <img src="./images/picture.png">
</body>
</html>
```

> the source file can be as a path relative to HTML file or an Webpack alias

minimal *webpack.config.js*:

```js
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require('html-bundler-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      entry: {
        // define templates here
        index: 'src/index.html',
      },
      js: {
        // output filename of compiled JavaScript
        filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
      },
      css: {
        // output filename of extracted CSS
        filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
      },
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|png|jp?g|svg)/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          // output filename of images
          filename: 'img/[name].[hash:8][ext]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

> An entry point is any HTML template.

The generated HTML contains output filenames:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="img/favicon.edda23bf.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
    <link href="css/styles.0f23efdf.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/main.5317c1f6.js" defer="defer"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <img src="img/picture.7b396424.png" />
  </body>
</html>
```

#### View the example in browser

[image: Open in StackBlitz]